# How can I add a value to the front of my linked list

Tags: c++

I need a function that will add a value to the front of the list. Everything I have tried does not work. Can someone show me what to do? I have cut out as much irrelevant code as possible for displaying purposes.

```
Link *fillLst(int);         //Fill a linked list, count backwards
void  prntLst(Link *);      //Print each data element in the list
void  destLst(Link *);      //Destroy the list/deallocate
Link * endLst(Link *);      //Find the end of the list
void   addLst(Link *,int);  //Add data at the end of the list
int   findLst(Link *,int);  //Determine what link contains the data
Link * fndLst(Link *,int);  //Determine address of link that contains  data
int    cntLst(Link *);      //How many elements are in the list


//Program Execution Begins Here

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    //Declare a pointer to the linked list and data to test in link creation
    Link *lnkList;
    int numList=8,valAdd=42,valFnd1=5,valFnd2=11;

}

//Function Create a linked list and fill with data
//Input  -> n      The number of elements in the list to create
//Output -> front  The address to the front of the allocated list.
Link *fillLst(int n){
    //Think of this part as the constructor
    Link *front=new Link;//Allocate a link at the front of the list
    front->data=n;       //Initialize with data
    front->linkPtr=NULL; //At the moment not pointing it to anything
    Link *next=front;    //Create a pointer to progress through the list

    //Fill the rest of the list with decreasing data down to 1
    n--;
    do{
       Link *temp=new Link; //Allocate a new link
       temp->data=n;        //Fill with data
       temp->linkPtr=NULL;  //Place at the end
       next->linkPtr=temp;  //Hook the new link to the end of the list
       next=temp;           //Move the pointer to the end
    }while(--n>0);          //Continue till you count down to Zero
    //Exit by return the original link pointer
    return front;           //Return the front pointer to the list
}

//Function Print the entire contents of the linked list
//Input -> front  The address to the front of the allocated list.
//Output-> Display the entire linked list.
void  prntLst(Link *front){
    Link *next=front;           //Create a pointer to the list
    cout<<endl<<"The Beginning of the List"<<endl;
    do{
        cout<<next->data<<endl; //Print the contents of the link
        next=next->linkPtr;     //Go to the next link in the list
    }while(next!=NULL);         //Loop until reaching the end
    cout<<"The End of the List"<<endl<<endl;
}

//Function Find the address of the last link in the list
//Input -> front  The address to the front of the allocated list.
//Output-> The address of the last link in the list
Link  *endLst(Link *front){
    Link *temp=front,*next; //Declare pointers used to step through the list
    do{
        next=temp;          //Point to the current link with a swap
        temp=temp->linkPtr; //Point to the next link
    }while(temp!=NULL);     //Your done when you hit the end
    return next;
}

//Function Add a link and data to the end of the list
//Input -> front  The address to the front of the allocated list.
//         data   Data to embed at the last link in the list
void   addLst(Link *front,int data){
    Link *last=endLst(front);  //Find the last link
    Link *add=new Link;        //Create the new link
    add->data=data;            //Add the data
    add->linkPtr=NULL;         //Set the pointer to NULL
    last->linkPtr=add;         //Point to the new end of the list
}
```

Comment: *I need a function that will add a value to the front of the list* -- Why do you need a special function?  Insertion should work, regardless of where in the linked list the value is being inserted.  That doesn't require writing a new function, that requires you to debug your code, as your insertion code does not work correctly.

Comment: Why concentrate on only the front part of the list?  Where is the general function to insert *anywhere* into the list?  You're going to have 3 separate functions for front, somewhere in the middle, and back?  Second, when you write a linked list, you should have worked this out with pencil and paper, drawing lines for the links and boxes for the data to see how to insert anywhere in the list.  Then translate what is on paper to code.

Comment: The comment section is for comments.  I commented.  And what is not helpful about stating the obvious -- when you get a linked list assignment, you are to draw on paper all the requisite operations, so that you're not stuck when it comes time to taking what you see on paper, and applying it in code.

Comment: There are 2 kinds of people who ask questions at this site: those who want to learn, and those who want someone else to do their work for them. When you post snarky comments at someone who takes the time to offer excellent advice, it says a lot about which kind of person you are. Also you clearly don't have a clue how this site works, so I suggest you look the the [help centre](http://stackoverflow.com/help).

Comment: Please read about [ask] questions here. Please also read the ["Be Nice"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/be-nice) policy.

Answer (score 1):

It is similar to the way you created linked list. You need to create a node, and append the remaining list to it.

```
Link* addLst(Link *front, int n) {
    Link *node = new Link      //Create a new node to add to 
    node -> data = n;          //Add the data
    add -> linkPtr = front;    //Set the pointer to front
    front = node               //Point front to the new node created
    return front;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply, but that did not work.